# application for changing fonts in android 4.3

Tags: applications, languages, fonts

Is there any appication by which you can change the fonts of your android, which it also supports greek language?

Unfortunatrlly, I don't own a well known brand, but somehow I managed to root it!

Comment: I am not sure if it supports Greek, but [Language Enabler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wanam) looks promising.